# Hide dates of other months in datepicker plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, datepicker

I'm using a datepicker from [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/) and customizing its CSS according to my needs. Now i want to hide all other dates that are not active i.e. dates shown of other months. I don't know if it can be done with CSS or i need to use jQuery for that. 
Here is an image that explains what i really want. [IMAGE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QAH3.png) 
Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({           
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
    });
});
```

Comment: You mean the past dates?

Comment: Yes both the past and the future dates.

Comment: What do you mean by future dates? What dates do you want active then?

Comment: Added the image which explains what i want. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Wouldn't `showOtherMonths: false` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting selectOtherMonths option to false would solve the problem. You may even remove that line, since the defaults for that option is set to false